# Tags in user search are not escaped

Tags: bug, status-completed, users

Visit https://stackoverflow.com/users
Type in "Jon Skeet" in the "Type to find users" textbox.
Click on "C#" under his name/reputation.

This goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#
It should go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

Comment: Yeah, gonna guess that on most days you won't actually have to search to find Jon Skeet.  He'll be on the front page with that tag.  Every.  Day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch, added missing UrlEncode